# How to solve the jpa error?

Tags: google-app-engine

i created one web application for accessing google bigtable.
but i shows the following error how to solve this

Description Resource Path Location Type
Your Web Application Project must be configured to use a JDK in order to use JSPs. guestbook.jsp /cftljpa/war Unknown Google App Engine Problem

how to solve this

Comment: I'm sure typing that error message into Google would tell you why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the local App Engine server and the deployment process need to run javac in order to compile your JSPs. If your project isn't set to use a JDK ("Java Development Kit", which includes javac), then the JSPs can't be compiled.
Go to Preferences > Java > Installed JREs and make sure that you have a JDK installed -- if you don't, you can easily download one. Now right-click on your project and choose **Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries** and make sure that your project is using this JDK